# Save Temp Word Perl Single Quote

Tags: perl, temp

i am trying to save hello world with single quote in temporary file 
i open temporary file hello world show without single quote
how to solve this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
chomp($TMPFILE = `mktemp bumatinaskk.XXXXXXXXXX`);
$echo = "echo \'hello word\' >>$TMPFILE";
system ("$echo");
```

Comment: 1) you should put "use strict;" in all of your Perl programs. 2) try print()ing $echo to see what you have put in there (then fix it so that you put in there what you really intended to put in there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
use IO::File qw();

my ($file_handle, $file_name) = tempfile('bumatinaskk.XXXXXXXXXX', UNLINK => 1);
$file_handle->say(q{'hello world'});
$file_handle->close;
say "wrote into temporary file $file_name";

sleep 30;   # giving you some time to inspect the temporary file

END { say 'temporary file is going to be deleted now' }
```

---

Documentation: [File::Temp](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aTemp), [IO::File](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aFile)